# How to specify the location for FileReference.browse() in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have a requirement to select a file from fileReference.browse(), but I want to browse a file to specific location say `D:\Dir\file` instead of the OS specific (The dialog box is native to the user's operating system).

Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance-

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using File, I'm assuming you're using the Air runtime.  To do this, you just need to set the path in the file constructor before you browser; like this:

```
var file:File = new File(somePath);
file.browse();
```

The only problem with this is that if you set it as an absolute path (like say, "c:\Users\SomeUser"), it might not work on Macs or Linux computers.  Be sure to use some of the File class' built in static properties when you can, like these:

- File.applicationStorageDirectory—a storage directory unique to each installed AIR application
- File.applicationDirectory—the read-only directory where the application is installed (along with any installed assets)
- File.desktopDirectory—the user's desktop directory
- File.documentsDirectory—the user's documents directory
- File.userDirectory—the user directory